# Install blender 2.79 in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: gpu, installation

i got a raspberry 4B 8GB. and in the Raspbian OS Blender 2.79 works super fine. But the OS performance its terrible. So i installed Ubuntu 20.10 and came with Blender 2.83 but DOESN'T RUN, so i want to install the 2.79 version but doesn't exist in the Ubuntu Repository. So. How i can install Blender 2.79 without call Blender 2.83 instead?

Thanks a lot